# image gallery with on hover overlaying another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, gallery

okie here it is what i am trying to do..

i have a image and i want o over lay another image on it at corners.

imagine a square as a image and am overlaying two images at the specific edges of square on mouse hover.

i am creating a image gallery. the main images are will be in image folder and the image to be overlay are in /image/overlay/pathtoimage..... as i am trying to overlay two images per main image and as it is a gallery i don't want to write specification for each gallery-image.
so i need a JavaScript to dynamically switch between overlay image paths.

can anybody help me with this JavaScript

Comment: Code Code Code Code . ?? Any example fiddle ?? what u tried ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/KdnJQ/26/

Comment: whats the above fiddle for??

Comment: i need to know how to dynamically switch between overlaying images??